# logrotate rename files with date

Tags: lighttpd, logrotate

Right now, logrotate renames old log files to access.log.1.gz, access.log.2.gz, etc.
I would prefer if it named them access.log.20090714.gz, access.log.20090715.gz, etc - one for each day.

I cannot find any option of specifying a filename pattern for the old log files. Do you know how to do this?

BTW, this is for rotating lighttpd log files, if that matters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In `/etc/logrotate.conf` or `/etc/logrotate.d/lighttpd`, or the proper file if anywhere else, add `dateext` to the stanza you want to apply date suffixes.

More information from [logrotate man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate):

> **dateext**
>
> > Archive old versions of log files adding a daily extension like YYYYMMDD
> >     instead of simply adding a number.

Comment: While the other answers may also yield the results I need, this one is the simplest. Even though it does not provide the same exact file name I initially desired, it does accomplish the task I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use cronolog - it'll write logfiles with the correct filenames in the first place (eg. I generally have my webservers write logfiles as YYYY/MM/DD/access, or YYYY/MM/DD/error, and so forth). More details on configuring cronolog with lighttpd are here: http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/MigratingFromApache

(while that page mentions that server.errorlog can't be run through cronolog, there appears to be a bug report for this that has been marked as "fixed" - unfortunately i can't post more than one URL at a time, since I'm a "new" user on serverfault...)

Comment: Cool. We use cronolog on apache, but I didn't think it worked on lighttpd.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that lighttpd or logrotate can do this by themselves. I see two options to achieve this:

Do your own scripting directly after logrotate, like at the end of it's cronjob. Something like:

```
if [ -f /var/log/lighttpd/access.log.1.gz ]; then`
    mv /var/log/lighttpd/access.log.1.gz /var/log/lighttpd/access.log.$date.gz
fi
```

Or, syslog-ng can build log files by date, and lighttpd can send logs to syslog rather than writing them itself.

```
# syslog-ng.conf
destination df_lighttpd { file("/var/log/lighttpd/$YEAR$MONTH$DAY.log"); };
filter f_lighttpd { program("lighttpd"); };
log { source(s_all);  filter(f_lighttpd); destination(df_lighttpd); };
```

and set `accesslog.use-syslog` & `server.errorlog-use-syslog` in the lighttpd conf.

---

**Edit:** Cronolog is simpler and/or than either of my suggestions, I'd go with that if it works for you.

Comment: date environment variable doesn't exist, you should replace $date by  `date +"%Y%m%d"` (don't forget backquote before and after this command that are hidden)